# Update desde java

Tags: java, update

Buenas quería modificar datos en `phpmyadmin` desde java y tengo el siguiente fragmento de código:

```
    public void modificarCliente(){
    Connection miConexion;
    PreparedStatement ps;
    try {    




  miConexion=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306
 /fastfoodcompany", "root", "quepasachavales3");



        String query="UPDATE clientes SET Nombre= ? AND Appelido1 = ? AND 
Apellido2 = ? WHERE Id = ?" ;

        Nombre=modificarcliente.getTxtNombre().getText();
        Apellido1=modificarcliente.getTxtSegundoApellido().getText();
        Apellido2=modificarcliente.getTxtSegundoApellido().getText();
        Id=modificarcliente.getTxtId().getText();

       ps=miConexion.prepareStatement(query);
       ps.setString(1, Nombre);
       ps.setString(2, Apellido1);
       ps.setString(3, Apellido2);
       ps.setString(4, Id);

        ps.executeUpdate();


        JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Datos actualizados");
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(bdFFC.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "No se han podido actualizar los datos"+ex);
    }
}
```

pero me salta el siguiente error por ejemplo si quiero cambiar el nombre:

> com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Truncated
>   incorrect DOUBLE value: 'Julian'

Espero que puedan ayudarme.

Comment: Dificilmente te va a actualizar en phpmyadmin pues phpmyadmin no es una BBDD si no un software para acceder a mysql.

Comment: Hay un campo que se llama `Appelido1` no sería `Apellido1`? En la query

Comment: @daniel gil benedi, edita bien la pregunta, podrías solo haber puesto el error que te daba en la pregunta y el código, nada mas, por otro lado el error que te da es por la sintaxis del update, abajo la respuesta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu error se debe a una mala implementación de la clase PreparedStatement y un error en tu instrucción SQL, aquí te dejo un ejemplo de cual sería su correcta implementación:

```
try {    

   miConexion=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306
   /fastfoodcompany", "root", "quepasachavales3");

   PreparedStatement stmt = miConexion.prepareStatement("UPDATE clientes SET Nombre= ?, Apellido1 = ?, Apellido2 = ? WHERE Id = ?");  

   //Asignación de valores
   stmt.setString(1, modificarcliente.getTxtNombre().getText());
   stmt.setString(2, modificarcliente.getTxtPrimerApellido().getText()); 
   stmt.setString(3, modificarcliente.getTxtSegundoApellido().getText()); 
   stmt.setInt(4, Integer.parseInt(modificarcliente.getTxtId().getText())); 

   stmt.executeUpdate();
   JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Datos actualizados");
} catch (SQLException ex) {
   Logger.getLogger(bdFFC.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
   JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "No se han podido actualizar los datos"+ex);
}
```

Recuerda que con PreparedStatment primero se crea la instrucción (query), luego se le asignan datos y posteriormente se ejecuta. Cada uno de los ? que se coloquen dentro de la instrucción SQL debe ser asignado su valor en el mismo orden comenzando desde el número 1.

Nota: El nombre de los campos Nombre, Apellido1, etc. que se encuentran dentro de la instrucción UPDATE no hacen mención a variables sino a campos de un registro que deseas actualizar.

Answer (score 1):

No necesitas usar el AND para el update lo correcto seria:

```
  "UPDATE clientes 
   SET Nombre= ? ,
   Appelido1 = ? , 
   Apellido2 = ? 
   WHERE Id = ?"
```

Sintaxis Correcta:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1 = value1, column2 = value2, ...
WHERE condition;
```

Si te fijas siempre debes usar las comas es por eso que tienes el error `Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value`